# Why is a separate Catalyst Registration Transaction required before voting?

Tags: catalyst

According to Cardano Improvement proposal 15 [CIP15](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip15/), Catalyst voting happens on a side chain and one needs to "register" to participate on this side chain by submitting a registration transaction on the mainnet chain. The registration metadata contains following

- "voting key" to be included in the side chain.
- Associates mainnet ADA to this voting key
- Declare an address to receive Catalyst rewards

Out of these three parameters, the staking mechanism provides two parameters for every wallet staked. The amount of staked ADA and reward receiving address.

If the voting key is also made part while wallet is staked, then there is no requirement for a separate "Registration for Voting" process.

What is wrong with this approach, why is a separate registration process being followed?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question here (a very good answer).  I think you could put most of the text in an answer and replace the current text with a short explanation of the registration transaction that is required.  This also helps get the site out of beta.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is mostly correct.

We need at least one transaction including your Catalyst key in the metadata and associating it with your staking account. There is no other way to do this since your Catalyst key is derived from your wallet private key and requires a signing step. After that happens, it is possible to not require any additional registration transactions in future Catalyst rounds, since your wallet balance can always be inferred from your staking account. But while this is technically possible, it's something that the community should agree upon first, so that all involved entities adapt to this new registration process.

Comment: I do not get it. You do not need to make a transaction to sign something.

Comment: You need a transaction to *commit* that signed message. You can create a message with your registration data and sign it without submitting it to the blockchain., and instead just submit this message directly to the Catalyst app. But then there is no way to prove that you registered.